# CSS3 arrows not working in webkit

Tags: css, webkit

Trying to get CSS3 arrows working in webkit browsers but I think I miss something, the code is working in firefox.

```
<div class="box">
    <h3>Box Inside</h3>
</div>​

.box {
    padding: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #DDDDDD;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    position:relative;
}

.box:after {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #fff;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 9px;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: -12%;
    top: 10px;
    width: 0;
```

}​

Example on: http://jsfiddle.net/fJkH8/

Comment: you're looking something like this? http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Comment: @wandarkaf I see this but I want it to be like a border without a background. like how it appears in Firefox

Answer (score 1):

Try this, this works in firefox and chrome:
http://cssarrowplease.com/

Comment: The problem is that I use :before for another thing with the same box other than the arrow, so I want to done it with :after. I wonder how it works in Firefox.

Comment: you are looking something like this? 
http://jsfiddle.net/chriscoyier/taaGc/1/
Thanks

Comment: I want something like that appears in Firefox. without any background, just borders. Thanks

Comment: As I know without using :before element in the css we cannot add border color to the arrow

Comment: And I think so too, this is the big problem, but I still wonder how this works in Firefox?. I'm building a time line and used a border instead of the arrow like so http://imm.io/POaD . Really Thanks